# Force dig to forget records

Tags: dns, cache, dig

I would like to let dig always forget a DNS record.
I mean if I do `dig yahoo.com` then I have a record back in with ttl for 1790 seconds.
Even if I have no cache service installed, next time i do the same command, the ttl have lowered.
Some how, dig do remember the answer. Is it possible to clear that, so I always get a fresh answer back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dig` doesn’t remember queries. But it makes use of name servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`, unless the server to be queried is specified explicitly. Such servers normally accept recursive queries and have caches for their results. So `dig` can receive records cached by (intermediate) servers.

Use
   `dig +trace` …
to override this behaviour, forcing it to query an authoritative server. See dig(1) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want a cached answer, ask directly the authoritative DNS serveur with `@`.

Example: `dig yahoo.com @ns1.yahoo.com`